# Seeking documentation for Apex slicer on AirWolf 3D printer

Tags: slicing

I have been, unsuccessfully, in contact with AirWolf and have concluded that there is no formal documentation available for their Apex slicer software that would explain what all the various parameters do and what the ramifications are.

Since the Apex slicer is supposedly based on the Cura slicer, I am now wondering what would be the appropriate version of Cura to research.

Comment: Good chance it is using a Cura library for slicing used on top of their own developed GUI (e.g. Windows DLL, depending on your platform), if you can locate it in the installation folder, the version in the file properties could possibly give you some information on the version.